# Installing GitHub for Mac - "Github cannot be opened because of a probem"

Tags: macos, git, github

I'm trying to get started using Git for Mac, but I receive an error when I try to run the program.  I'm new to GitHub and relatively new to Mac.

First, I installed Git using the downloadable .dmg file named "git-1.7.12.3-intel-universal-snow-leopard".  I ran the .pkg file contained therein and the install seemed to work fine.  I'm using a new macbook pro w/ retina.  Then I downloaded the Github for Mac installer, "mac_GitHub for Mac 69.zip".  When I double-click the file, it shows that there is a single file of type "Application".  Double-clicking that application file produces the error: "GitHub cannot be opened because of a problem".  Here are the partial details of that error:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Rebel.framework/Rebel
  Referenced from: /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Rebel.framework/Rebel: file too short
    /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Rebel.framework/Rebel: file too short
```

Comment: Try to drag and drop this application to your application folder and then run it.

Comment: I did try that with the same result.

Comment: Try contacting Github support?

Comment: I've emailed them.  I'll post the response when I receive it.  I was hoping it was a simple mistake on my part.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? `git` has come with OS X since at least 10.7 (Lion).

Comment: version 10.8.2.  Should I uninstall the GIT package?  If so, how?

Comment: No response from GitHub support.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the .zip file using 'unzip' utility on your mac. That worked for me. I ran into this issue when I used other tools to unzip the downloaded mac_GitHub file.